# How to get Site name dynamically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to Change Title and No of Links in Recent Changes of Sharepoint 2010's Wiki page library. 
I made one custom **user control** for that. It work fine but there is one problem that I am unable to pass the url of site in

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteCollection))
```

I have to pass SiteCollection Statically. I want to make it dynamic. Mine site is a sub site. Is it possible to get Site link to open the Web..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just use:

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site
```

the same goes for using a subsite:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web
```

No need for using statements if you use the context, you dont need to dispose it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this : `SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url`.

Answer (score -1):

Nipesh,

You can getting all Webs using below code

```
        SPSite rootSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
        foreach (SPWeb oWeb in rootSite.AllWebs)
        {
            //This Using for SPSite is optional 
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(oWeb.Url))
            {
                //This Using for SPWeb is optional 
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                   //You can get all web in this object & perform operation
                }
            }
            oWeb.Dispose();
        }
```

Above both Using for SPSite & SPWeb are optional you can direct access SPWeb object from oWeb object.

Happy Coding...!!!

Comment: -1: The statements about using are wrong. new Site() and site.Open() always have to be disposed. Reopening the web makes no sense at all. `oWeb` and `point` are pointing to the same object. Plus, this does not answer the question...